# enable linger for user fails with bad message

Tags: linux, systemd, sles

I currently have the problem of not being able to activate linger for my user. The test activation for the user root, was possible. I am unfortunately overwhelmed with the error message and can not come up with an idea for the cause of the error.

```
# loginctl enable-linger appadm
Failed to look up user appadm: Bad message
```

When I display a list of users from loginctl, I only see root.

It is systemd version 249 on SLES15

Comment: Can you attempt to restart logind with `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`, and re-run your command after restarting logind?

Comment: no change in the error.